# Hall effect of Metal and Semiconductor

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, metals, hall-effect

I am pretty much confused in the topic of Hall effect, as it is discussed in Metals and Semiconductor. My question is -

1. Hall effect in Metals is due to electron as they are in majority, so hall coefficient is negative. But experimentally it is seen that for some metals Hall Effect is positive. What is the explanation for this in Kittle's book.
2. What is Hall coefficient for Intrinsic semiconductor and Extrinsic (p and n type) semiconductor. Should it be like, for p-type, it must be positive and for n-type, it must be negative as holes and electron are the majority charge carrier. And then what about Intrinsic semiconductor.

Comment: The issue is that we don’t talk about holes until the curriculum hits semiconductors, ignoring the fact that there are holes in metals as well. (Much simpler holes, since detailed balance does not apply.) So, the explanation for metals is sometimes the holes are more important than the electrons for conduction.

Comment: Do these answer the 2nd part of your question: [Hall effect with similar positive and negative carriers?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86431/145491) and [How do the effects of semiconductor doping affect the Hall effect?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79220/145491)?